# Hotkey to bring the taskbar to the front

Tags: windows, windows-8

I'm running two games in windowed fullscreen mode, so they fill the entire screen and cover the taskbar. Back in Windows 7, if I pressed the Windows Key the start menu would open and the taskbar would come to the front.

Now, in Windows 8, the start screen opens, but the taskbar stays hidden. Is there any hotkey I can use to bring the taskbar (temporarily) to the front?

Comment: If you move mouse pointer to the screen bottom, then the taskbar should appear.